# can omniauth-google-oauth2 be used also to get calendar info back from the google calendar API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, google-calendar-api, oauth-2.0, omniauth

Can omniauth-google-oauth2 be used also to get calendar info back from
the google calendar API?

I have managed to so far to get:
a) omniauth-google-oauth2 test rails app working to "sign on with
google" in test app 1
b) OAuth Plugin to get calendar data via the Oauth Calendar Data API
in test app 2.

QUESTION is whether I could drop the use of "OAuth Plugin" and just
use "omniauth-google-oauth2" to also (after authentication) get the
calendar data?   If yes, how would this work?  Are the OAuth tokens
the same from google for the authentication & google calendar api
aspects?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be used to get calendar data.

I only use the omniauth-google-oauth2 gem for calendar access.
I would assume it works the same way as the oauth plugin with the token.

Check out this to get started https://github.com/deafgreatdane/google_oauth_calendar

Answer (score 0):

For future searchers:

You can simply include `calendar` in the scope for your `google_oauth2` provider.

```
provider :google_oauth2,
         ENV["GOOGLE_OAUTH2_APP_ID"],
         ENV["GOOGLE_OAUTH2_APP_SECRET"],
         { scope: 'email,profile,calendar' }
```

More details [here](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2#configuration).